# Reading file resource in Unix and MacOS

Tags: embedded-resource, multiplatform

I am writing my first wxWidgets application which aims to be cross-platform. The program uses dll file for plugins and in Windows, reads dll resource part for information regarding plugin name, author name etc.

I have never used Unix or MacOS (little Linux though) and am wondering whether compiling binary for these other OSes will require changes to the code written for Windows. For instance, is there a DLL equivalent in Unix and MacOS? Are there any provisions of compiling resource strings and files into a such files?

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

Both Unix and OS X have dynamically-linked libraries. Unix has `.so` files (usually, but some use other extensions), and OS X has `.dylib`. Neither really supports resources in the same manner as Windows DLLs though. Resources on *nix are usually provided as separate files.

P.S.: "MacOS" usually refers to version 8 or 9. "OS X" is the name used for the *nix variant.